# Site that creates an image with an uploaded photo on a Mac?

Tags: images, mockup

Is there a site/software that can aid in the design of an image that shows a Mac/PC with my product/screenshot displayed.

I once found a site that enabled you to upload an image, choose a type of device (eg. Mac), then produced an image of that Mac with your image on the screen, but have lost the link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, this type of question isn't on topic here. Next time, I'd try http://reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I think you are looking for [Place It!](https://placeit.net)

Here is the direct link to the [Framer](https://placeit.net/#!/stages/325)

It used to have a different address I think. If it's not the one you meant, it is pretty sweet alternative that does what you are looking for.